# ASP.NET : How to store placeholder in viewstate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I am trying to develop a page.
that has a button and a placeholeder.
on the click of the button a user control is added to the placeholder.

**on each click of button that many user controls should be added to the placeholder.**

i am trying to store placeholder in viewstate on preinit event but while retrieving placeholder from viewstate in load event viewstate remains null.

below is my code:

```
  protected void PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.OnPreInit(e);
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                ViewState["c"] = PlaceHolder1;

            }
            else { PlaceHolder1 = (PlaceHolder)ViewState["c"]; }
        }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if(IsPostBack)
        { PlaceHolder1=  (PlaceHolder)ViewState["c"]; }

        }


 public void addDepartmentBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // User Control Code


            c1 = LoadControl("~/AddDepartment.ascx");
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(c1);
}
```

**If viewstate is not suitable in this scenarion then what is the alternative way to achieve this ?**

Comment: By storing in the ViewState, you mean the controls inside the placeholder?

Comment: Does PlaceHolder1 control exist in the markup?

Comment: @ System Down: On first button click my user control is inside placeholder. Now I wanna store placeholder in viewstate. On next subsequent button clicks placeholder sholud get retrieved from the viewstate as new user controls are added to the placeholder.

Comment: @Igor: Yes its in markup

Comment: It is not a good practice to store Placeholder inside ViewState. What is your requirement anyhow?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add controls to the page dynamically, that must be done in Init *on each postback.*  This means that you must use a data structure (something persisted in ViewState will do) as a list of dynamically-created controls- NOT the controls themselves, but a hash of strings to use as IDs is a common method.

Each time the user does something to add a control to the page, add a key to the list.  In the Page Init, you must then read the list and use it to recreate and add the dynamic controls back to the page collection or they will not appear on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You have to re-add controls to your place holder on each post back.

Your attempt to ViewState is barking up the wrong tree-- ViewState is for something entirely different and even if you wanted to, you can only store serializable things into ViewState.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work. ASP.NET server controls are too complex a thing to be stored in a ViewState. What server controls do, by ASP.NET design, is store their data (state, property values, etc) in Page's ViewState.

What you can do is store in ViewState the number of AddDepartment user controls that have been created and added to the placeholder. This can be done in PreRender. Then on postback, you read this number from the ViewState and create and add to placeholder that many AddDepartment controls.